# Get transmission download directory from cli

Tags: transmission

Is there a way to see the current download location for a torrent using transmission-remote? In the web interface you can view and set the individual torrent's location, but unless i'm missing something, this option is not available in transmission-remote? (-w only sets the global location or sets the location when adding a torrent).

Is there a way to extract it from the torrent files in /var/lib/transmission-deamon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the default download directory with the `--session-info` (`-si`) option:

```
transmission-remote host:port -si
```

Output:

```
VERSION
  Daemon version: 4.0.4 (24077e3511)
  RPC version: 17
  RPC minimum version: 14

CONFIG
  Configuration directory: /data/transmission-home
  Download directory: /data/download
  Listenport: 49115
  Portforwarding enabled: No
  uTP enabled: No
  Distributed hash table enabled: Yes
  Local peer discovery enabled: No
  Peer exchange allowed: Yes
  Encryption: required
  Maximum memory cache size: 4.00 MiB

LIMITS
  Peer limit: 240
  Default seed ratio limit: Unlimited
  Upload speed limit: 12.50 MB/s (Enabled limit: 12.50 MB/s; Disabled turtle limit: 5.00 MB/s)
  Download speed limit: 50.00 MB/s (Enabled limit: 50.00 MB/s; Disabled turtle limit: 5.00 MB/s)

MISC
  Autostart added torrents: Yes
  Delete automatically added torrents: No
```

And you can get it for a specific torrent with the `--info` (`-i`) option:

```
transmission-remote host:port -t 1 -i
```

Output:

```
NAME
  Id: 1
  Name: debian-live-12.2.0-amd64-lxqt.iso
  Hash: a920aca5550cf0cc1c1675a92220b5733128fafc
  Magnet: magnet:?xt=urn:btih:a920aca5550cf0cc1c1675a92220b5733128fafc&dn=debian-live-12.2.0-amd64-lxqt.iso&tr=http%3A%2F%2Fbttracker.debian.org%3A6969%2Fannounce&ws=https%3A%2F%2Fcdimage.debian.org%2Fcdimage%2Frelease%2F12.2.0-live%2Fiso-hybrid%2Fdebian-live-12.2.0-amd64-lxqt.iso&ws=https%3A%2F%2Fcdimage.debian.org%2Fcdimage%2Farchive%2F12.2.0-live%2Fiso-hybrid%2Fdebian-live-12.2.0-amd64-lxqt.iso
  Labels: 

TRANSFER
  State: Idle
  Location: /data/download
  Percent Done: 100%
  ETA: 0 seconds (0 seconds)
  Download Speed: 0 kB/s
  Upload Speed: 0 kB/s
  Have: 3.21 GB (3.21 GB verified)
  Availability: 100%
  Total size: 3.21 GB (3.21 GB wanted)
  Downloaded: 3.21 GB
  Uploaded: 2.18 GB
  Ratio: 0.6
  Corrupt DL: None
  Peers: connected to 0, uploading to 0, downloading from 0
  Web Seeds: downloading from 0 of 2 web seeds

HISTORY
  Date added:       Fri Oct 13 09:04:27 2023
  Date finished:    Fri Oct 13 09:14:08 2023
  Date started:     Sun Nov 26 04:02:27 2023
  Latest activity:  Mon Nov 27 02:25:13 2023
  Downloading Time: 9 minutes (580 seconds)
  Seeding Time:     40 days (3513509 seconds)

ORIGINS
  Date created: Sat Oct  7 14:10:46 2023
  Public torrent: Yes
  Comment: "Debian CD from cdimage.debian.org"
  Creator: mktorrent 1.1
  Piece Count: 12252
  Piece Size: 256.0 KiB

LIMITS & BANDWIDTH
  Download Limit: Unlimited
  Upload Limit: Unlimited
  Ratio Limit: Default
  Honors Session Limits: Yes
  Peer limit: 60
  Bandwidth Priority: Normal
```

You're also correct that `-w` sets the global download directory, or sets it for the specific torrent when you add it.

It's not possible to change the download directory for an active torrent download.

Comment: Ah, stupid me. I did the -i option, but for some reason I had it piped through sort and it filtered out most of the information. I must be blind.